Guy uses bike to recharge, and a guy who remains frozen most of the time
The two things I can remember is a guy with a bike who uses electricity to charge himself and a guy who has to remain frozen most of the time. Does anyone know which movie this is?

Sounds like the pilot episode of Misfits of Science, (1985), titled Deep Freeze.  The show was

an American superhero fantasy television series that aired on NBC from
  October 1985 to February 1986. It features super-powered humans and
  their madcap adventures.

Its characters included

Johnny "Johnny B" Bukowski – a rock and roll musician who was
  electrocuted on stage, thus giving him formidable electrical powers.
  Johnny continually drains any electrically charged items in his
  surroundings, forcing him to live in isolation.

and, in the pilot episode only,

Arnold "Beef"/"Ice Man" Beifneiter – got his power to freeze anything
  he touches from placing himself in an experimental cryogenic suspended
  animation unit back in 1937 due to grief caused by the loss of his
  beloved Amelia Earhart. The team drives around in an ice cream truck
  because the lumbering and now rather simpleminded Ice Man dies if he
  gets too warm, so they keep him in the freezer.


Thank you very much for your help. This is
exactly what I was looking for. Once again, Thanks!

Another hit-n-run. +1 because you deserve it.
